# Replacing a line in a file with PHP

Tags: php, string, line, strpos

I am currently trying to replace a line in a configuration file to update a version. The line looks like `requiredBuild = 123456;` and I need to change the numbering. I have got the following which inserts the new line after it, but I need to actually replace the existing line instead.

How would this be accomplished? ftell() is giving me the POS after the line I want to replace but removing the original line is where I am confused. Is there some way to just do like the ftell() - strlen(thisline) and replace it with ''?

```
<?

    $config = 'serverDZ.cfg';

    $file=fopen($config,"r+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    $insertPos=0;

    while (!feof($file))
    {
        $line=fgets($file);

        if (strpos($line, 'requiredBuild') !== false)
        {
            $insertPos = ftell($file);
            $newline =  "requiredBuild = 124971;\n";

            break;
        }
    }

    fseek($file, $insertPos);
    fwrite($file, $newline);

    fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: have you heard of `sed`? This is a great opportunity to learn it!

Comment: I had not, was previously using FART but it doesn't work in this case. SED looks perfect but I am trying to keep it very lightweight since I have to deploy it as an update to various servers and then cleanup all the files once its runs, why I chose a single PHP file. Is it going to be complicated to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<?php
$content = file($path);

foreach ($content as $line_num => $line) {
    if (false === (strpos($line, 'requiredBuild'))) continue;

    $content[$line_num] = "requiredBuild = 124971;\n";
}

file_put_contents($path, implode($content));
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly! I will have to remember this solution in the future as it is actually very simple seeing it now. Thanks